# Prove the convergence of a sequence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis

The problem says:

"Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Define $g_{n}\left ( x \right )=f(x^{n})$ for $n=1,2,...$ . Prove that $\left \{ \int_{0}^{1}g_{n}(x)dx \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty }$ converges to $f(0)$"

I got this idea for this:

"The limit which  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }(\int_{0}^{1}g_{n}(x)dx)=\int_{0}^{1}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }g_{n}(x))dx$, but

$\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(f(x^{n}))dx=\int_{0}^{1}(f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x^{n}))dx$, and then

$\int_{0}^{1}(f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x^{n}))dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(0)dx=f(0)$."

But I do not know if this approach is correct, and I would like to find a way of do this by $\varepsilon $-definition but I have no idea of how I can do this. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea here is exactly what you need for "insight."

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1 f(x^n)\,dx= \int_{0}^{1}(f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x^{n}))dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(0)dx=f(0) \tag{1}.$$

In fact in the 18th century that would have been a "proof."   Now you need to make it a bit more modern.  As you  say, put some $\epsilon$'s in the mix.  Better is to use some sophisticated theorems about convergence of integrals.

Start with this manipulation that puts (1) in a better lilght:

$$ \left|
\int_0^1 f(x^n)\,dx - f(0)\right| = \left|
\int_0^1 [f(x^n)-f(0)]\,dx \right| \leq \int_0^1|f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx . \tag{2} $$

**Problem I.**  Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is Lebesgue integrable and that $f$ is continuous at $0$.  Show that (1) is correct.

*Hint 1:*  Consider the sequence $\{f(x^n)-f(0)\}$.  Show it converges to zero a.e. and that the conditions of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem apply. [This is Mr Coudy's answer:  if $f$ is continuous then this sequence is uniformly bounded, if $f$ is just Lebesgue integrable the sequence is dominated by some integrable function.]

---

**Problem II.**  Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is  Riemann integrable and that $f$ is continuous at $0$.  Show that (1) is correct.

*Hint 2:*  Consider the sequence $\{f(x^n)-f(0)\}$.  Show it converges pointwise to a Riemann integrable function and that it is uniformly bounded. Thus conditions of Arzelà's bounded convergence theorem apply.

---

**Problem III.**  Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is  continuous.  Show that (1) is correct.

*Hint 3:*  Consider the sequence $\{f(x^n)-f(0)\}$.  Show it converges
uniformly to zero on any interval  $[0,b]$ for $0<b<1$.  From that you can conclude that $\int_0^b |f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx \to 0$.  Then check that  $\int_b^1 |f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx \to 0$ as $b\to 1-$. Etc.

*Hint 4:*  If you prefer a detailed epsilon/delta/N  proof.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Choose $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(0)|< \epsilon/2$ if $0\leq x \leq \delta$.  Choose $b<1$ so that $\int_b^1 |f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx < \epsilon/2$ for all $n$.

Choose an integer $N$ so that $b^N< \delta$.  Show that
$$\int_0^1 |f(x^n)-f(0)|\,dx < \epsilon$$
if $n\geq N$.

[Check the details--might need adjusting.  Will edit if anything messed up.]